# Get data-index of the parent tr

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with checkboxes in every row. No I want to get the data-index of the checked row. How do I get the data-index of the parent tr-Element?

**HTML**

```
 <table id="searchResultsDetails">
 <tbody>
  <tr data-index="0" class="selected">
    <td class="bs-checkbox">
    <input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
    </td><td >19/02/2015</td><td >Jendro</td><td >
 </tr>
 <tr data-index="1">
    <td class="bs-checkbox">
    <input data-index="1" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
    </td><td >13/02/2015</td><td >Ganten</td><td >
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#searchResultsDetails .bs-checkbox').change(function() {
    var parTr =  $(this).find('.bs-checkbox').index(this.parentNode);
    console.log('ParTr ', parTr);
});
```

Output is ParTr -1
Could you pls give me a hint, whats going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could traverse the DOM using the [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select the element with a `[data-index]` attribute. Then chain `.data('index')` to get the attribute's value.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cu2tLghn/)

```
$('#searchResultsDetails .bs-checkbox').change(function() {
    var parTr =  $(this).closest('[data-index]').data('index');
    console.log('ParTr ', parTr);
});
```

---

You may not need to rely on these attributes though. You could just select the closest `tr` element and then use the `.index()` method to determine the index of the `tr` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rkpw17yx/)

```
$(this).closest('tr').index();
```